# Tensorflow version in jupyter notebook does not match that in the conda env?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conda

I build a conda env with jupyter notebook, tensorflow-gpu and other stuff in it from conda-forge, on ubuntu 21.10.  I also did:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=condaenvname
```

However when I select the env/kernel I get a conflict.  After importing tensorflow as tf I get:

```
# what version of tensorflow is running in this env
print(tf.version.VERSION)
2.8.0
```

while when I do !conda list I get this:

```
tensorflow                2.6.2           cuda112py39h9333c2f_1    conda-forge
tensorflow-base           2.6.2           cuda112py39he9472f8_1    conda-forge
tensorflow-estimator      2.6.2           cuda112py39h9333c2f_1    conda-forge
tensorflow-gpu            2.6.2           cuda112py39h0bbbad9_1    conda-forge
```

How can this be?  How can I get jupyter to use the correct tf version and all other packages in the env?  I really don't want to rant because I know a lot of clever people are working hard on improving this, but I've read and worked on this for days, and can still not get a clear answer on how to get jupyter notebooks to call in the correct kernel and execute the correct package versions.  Thx. J

Answer (score 0):

I did finally find a solution to the problem.  Jupyter/tensorflow/python actually go and find all packages on the system associated with that version of python, so it was finding packages in my own directories at

```
~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

so erasing the site-packages directory and all of its contents, restarting the jupyter server solved all the problems.  This is a very poor software setup, the whole basis of a conda env is to create a new environment, unpolluted and uninfluenced by other software packages on the base system.  But apparently jupyter/python goes looking for all packages on the system, thus defeating the whole purpose of creating an environment in the first place!